# Drawing a line connecting similar points in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I am working on mapping schools and the students that attend the schools. The school shapefile has a field for school name and the student shapefile has a field for the school they attend.

I would like to draw a line connecting each student to their respective schools just for display purposes to show travel in a general sense. Not looking for routes, just as the crow flies.

Is there anyway to do this in a reasonable amount of time without much python, my python skills are lacking.

Comment: Check out the near tool and xy to line tool

Comment: Add geometry attributes to schools. Join this table to students table. Make XY layer from this table, convert to points. Merge with students; use points to line and student name/I'd as line id